# Sending message from AURA to LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I have a requirement to send messages from Aura component to an LWC component. The component exist on the
The Aura Component contain an LWC inside it,, i need if the tab of Aura is open the i need to inform the LWC component and send the required details...is this possible with LMS...not sure ,,didn't found the documentation for this one....kindly help me out how to start.

LMS Code as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>LightningMessageChannel</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Why to use LMS, if its a `child parent` scenario. Does this help : https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/15/pass-value-to-lwc-from-parent-aura-component/

Comment: There is no child paret Scenario

Comment: When you mention `The Aura Component contain an LWC inside it` , this is a child parent scenario, where child is LWC component and parent is Aura component. Or please rephrase the question if I have misunderstood.